# How to make a Google Maps Location Sharing URL for desktop?

Tags: google-maps, desktop-gis, location-sharing

On my cellphone's launcher, I have an icon I can press to see where family member 'Jeff' currently is in Google Maps.

How can I do the same on desktop?

I've reverse engineered it down to
`https://www.google.com/maps/@.../data=!...?entry=ttu`
but it doesn't fly to 'Jeff's location.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started?hl=en#map-action